# LU factorisation question

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I have a question from a past exam with the solution but i am getting a completely different answer to that of the solution. Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

question:

Find the elementary lower triangular matrices $L_1(m_1)$ and $L_2(m_2)$ which describe the gaussian elimination to bring the linear system

$Ax=b$,  $A=
\begin{pmatrix} 
  1   & 2 & 1\\ 
  -1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$ , $b=\begin{pmatrix} 
  1  \\ 
  8 \\
 4
\end{pmatrix}$

into the form $Ux=b'$ with an upper triangular $3 \times 3$ matrix $U$ and a new right hand side $b' \in \mathbb R$

**The solution says:**

We have that $L_1(m_1)L_2(m_2)A=U$

Where the vector multipliers are $m_1=\begin{pmatrix} 
  0  \\ 
  -1 \\
 2
\end{pmatrix}$
and $m_2=\begin{pmatrix} 
  0  \\ 
  0 \\
 \frac{-2}{3}
\end{pmatrix}$

**This is where i am stuck and where my answer is going wrong**

I would have thought that 
$m_2=\begin{pmatrix} 
  0  \\ 
  0 \\
 \frac{2}{2}=1
\end{pmatrix}$
and $e_1=\begin{pmatrix} 
  1  \\ 
  0 \\
  0
\end{pmatrix}$

$e_2=\begin{pmatrix} 
  0  \\ 
  1 \\
  0
\end{pmatrix}$ but then $L_1(m_1)=I-m_1e_1$ gives me a completely different answer. Am i wrong? If so please could you tell me exactly why?

The solution reads
$L_1(m_1)=I-m_1e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 
  1   & 0 & 0\\ 
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
-2 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

and $L_2(m_2)=I-m_2e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 
  1   & 0 & 0\\ 
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & \frac{2}{3} & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Is this printed exam solution wrong or am I wrong? **Note**Please answer is the same style as i have shown as i have to use this exact style of solution in my exam. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you need to find elementary matrices that brings your matrix

$$B=\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 &1 & 2 &8 \\2&2&4&4\end{array}\right)$$
in a form like this
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}\lambda_1 & * & * & * \\ 0 &\lambda_2 & * &* \\0&0&\lambda_3&*\end{array}\right)$$

If this is what you want then you need to remember that there are three types (actually four but two can be merged together) of elementary matrices:

**Row/Columnt multiplication elementary matrix**

This is a matrix that multiply a column or a row of your matrix by a scalar $\lambda$. It is often noted $S_i(\lambda)$ it is like the identity matrix, but it has the element $\lambda$ in the ii-th component. Remember that when you make the multiplication $S_i(\lambda)A$ you are going to **multiply by $\lambda$ the rows of $A$** and when you do the reverse multiplication, i.e. $AS_i(\lambda)$ you are going to **multiply the columns of A**. Keep this rule in mind. I'll give you an example.

Let $A= \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\end{pmatrix}$ and let $S_2(3)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$, then
$$S_2(3)A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\8&10&12\\7&8&9\end{pmatrix}$$
You can check by yourself $AS_2(3)$.

**Interchange of two rows/columns**
This matrix interchanges the i-th row\column with the j-th row column. It is noted $T_{ij}$ and it looks like this

[image]

For example let $A$ as before and $T_{13} = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ Then you will notice that

$$T_{13}A = \begin{pmatrix}7&8&9\\4&5&6\\1&2&3\end{pmatrix}$$

Again you can check $AT_{13}$

**Row\column addiction matrix**
This matrix sums $\lambda$ times the $j-th$ row\columns to the $i-th$ column. It is noted like $T_{ij}(\lambda)$ and it looks like this

[image]

Let $A$ as before and $T_{31}(3)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\3&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ then

$$T_{31}(3)A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\10&14&18\end{pmatrix}$$
You can check the reverse.

What is this for? All those matrices are used to bring a matrix $A$ in [Row Echelon Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)

You need to bring your system $B$ in Row echelon form, so the first thing you need to do is *add the first row to the second row*. This can be done by multiplying $T_{21}(1)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ by $B$, indeed 
$$T_{21}(1)B = \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 &3 & 3 &9 \\2&2&4&4\end{array}\right)=:B_1$$
Now you need to **add -2 times the first row to the third** Hence you need to multiply $T_{31}(-2)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\-2&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ by $B_1$. This is what you get
$$T_{31}(-2)B_1=\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 &3 & 3 &9 \\0&-2&2&2\end{array}\right)=:B_2$$ 
Notice that 
$$T_{21}(1)T_{31}(-2) = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\-2&0&1\end{pmatrix}=L_1(m_1)$$

Now what the last operation to bring $B_2$ in Row Echelong Form is the one to *add $\frac23$ time the second row to the third*. This can be done with $T_{23}\left(\frac23\right)$, indeed
$$T_{23}\left(\frac23\right)B_2 = \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 &3 & 3 &9 \\0&0&4&8\end{array}\right)$$

Notice also that $T_{23}\left(\frac23\right)=L_2(m_2)$

I hope this helps you, otherwise just ask :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your long and detailed answer! I can do it just by reducing the rows ect, but now i have been taught this new way where We have that $L_1(m_1)L_2(m_2)A=U$ and $L_1(m_1)L_2(m_2)=L$ hence A=LU. I think i am just getting the notation a bit mixed up. Could you please tell me how they have computed $m_2$?

Comment: Just looking at what you have done.. i think i can see it but the notation is slightly different so may have to write it out.. Do you use the result of $m_1$ to get $m_2$? If so i think i can see what you have done! I will write it out again and see if it makes sense. thanks so much i have been checking back all night to see if anyone had answered. :)

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews To be honest i don't really understand how they have computed it, but i can tell you how to compute it. It seems to me that the vector $m_1$ is the first column vector of $L(m_1)$ and that $m_2$ is the second column vector of $L(m_2)$ Now from my answer you can see that we get the first column vector $m_1$ by the first column vector of matrix $
T_{21}(1)T_{31}(-2)$ Indeed the indices on the first column bring the *zeros* on the first column of you system $B$. Hence you can take your $m_1$ to be the first column vector of $
T_{21}(1)T_{31}(-2)$

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews To get $m_2$ you need to take the *second* vector of the matrix $T_{23}\left(\frac23\right)$. Why? because this vector brings the indeces of $B$ in row echeln form. I think it is difficult to understand it just by reading my comments. I suggest you to do the calculation. You will notice that everytime that you multiply $B$ by an elementary matrix you do a step of the gaussian algorithm. At the end you can multiply together the matrices that modify the first column of $B$ and get the vector $m_1$ by taking the first vector of the multiplication

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews You multiply the matrices that modify the second column indeces of $B$ and take $m_2$ to be the second column vector of this multiplication and so on. I think that in the solution that you have they also computed the matrices i computed, they just didn't write them down because once you are familiar with this matrices you see immediately how the vectors $m_i$ look like. :)

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews. One **doesn't** use the result of $m_1$ to get $m_2$. You can get them independently, *but* it is convenient to get first $m_1$ secondly $m_2$ and so on, why? Because in the gaussian algorithm you first want to have all zeros in the first column of your system, then all zeros in the second and so on :)

Comment: thank you so much! ahh its really annoying i do LU basically just using gaussian usually. I was just confused because i didnt see how -2/3 could reduce the third row to 0 as subracting 2/3's of row 1 or 2 wouldnt leave it in the form i wanted it in! But I will go through this all again and write it out. Thanks so much :)

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews Ok, i was also confused when i first use those matrices, the way i got familiar with them was writing down simple examples, as i've written above, to see how they work. Write down every step that brings your intial system $B$ in row echelon form with the help of the elementary matrix, you can check that you get the exact matrices that i get and then everything should be fine. If you have questions just ask :)

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews did it work?

Comment: Hey, sorry went to sleep (it was 7am where i was haha!) but have just gone through it and it all makes sense finally so thank you! I was just tired and had some a wrong calculation hence couldnt get the 2/3 but i have now! Thanks so much :)

Comment: You are welcome :D